# Concise use of list addressing

Tags: list-manipulation

I very often work with `List`s of `List`s (trend data exported from other programs). Sometimes the start times of the important data are delayed independently in each source file (which forms a single `List`). I am looking for a shorthand way to take portions of each of the `List`s from different starting positions that is consistent with my favorite use of `Map`.

In the example below both Lists within `c` are selected started at the same index. I would like to have for example `c[[1,1;;]]` and `c[2,11;;]]` selected w/o having to specifically address each `List` independently. I know that there must be a concise `Map`/`Apply` of `{{1, 1 ;;}, {2, 11 ;;}}` into the `List` `c` method that will do this but it is currently beyond me.

```
a = RandomReal[1, 50];
b = Join[ConstantArray[0, 10], a];
c = {a,b};
mncn[x_] := x - Mean[x];
ListLinePlot[{.1 Range[Length[#]], (mncn[#]/(Max[#] - Min[#]))}\[Transpose] & /@ c[[All, 1 ;;]],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-.6, .6}}, 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, {"Run #1", "Run #2"}], 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Normalized Signal"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Trends"
 ]
```

Comment: `MapThread[f[#] & /@ Take[#1, #2] &, {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}},
  {{1, -1}, {2, -1}}}]`

Comment: george2079: Thanks. This works and was what I am looking for. Never thought of using `Take`. Define as an answer and I will accept.